# Default implementation of protocol for Enum

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, protocols

here is my code:

```
protocol Logable {
    func log()
}

extension Logable where Self: Error {
    func log() {
        switch self {
        case .Server(code: Int, message: String):
            print("code = \(code), message = \(message)")
        }
    }
}

enum Error: Logable {
    case Client(code: Int, message: String)
    case Server(code: Int, message: String)
}
```

As you see, I want to create default implementation for protocol `LogableError` for my enum `Error`. Maybe it's no possible - please provide the link. Don't run it in the playground, it won't show anything, but compiler gives error:
`type 'Self' constrained to non-protocol type 'Error'`

Comment: Try `Self == Error` in the protocol extension

Comment: @Roshan it gives `Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Self' non-generic`

Comment: Yeah, kinda had a hunch it wouldn't work... If you need to implement the protocol for a particular type, you would add an extension on the type itself instead of the protocol...

Comment: Note that "default implementation" doesn't make much sense for enums since you can't inherit from them anyway. I suspect the above solution may work if you replace enum with a strict(say, Int)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement `Logable` for `Error` you don't need a protocol extension, you just need an extension on `Error`.

```
protocol Logable {
    func logError()
}

enum Error {
    case Client(code: Int, message: String)
    case Server(code: Int, message: String)
}

extension Error : Logable {
    func logError() {
        switch self {
            case .Client(let code, let message):
                print("code = \(code), message = \(message)")

            case .Server(let code, let message):
                print("code = \(code), message = \(message)")
        }
    }
}
```